# Replacing Classes in the System Namespace

Tags: .net

I'm currently working to hack my .NET operating system into running on top of MS.NET/Mono (previously it ran bare-metal only), and I've hit a small snag.  I need to implement my own System.Console that talks to my service infrastructure, and I can't find a good way to replace it without either 1) not linking against mscorlib (would be hellacious to do), or 2) Using a NotQuiteSystem namespace for my replacements, which would break compatibility.

Is there a mechanism by which I can cleanly replace System classes without doing one of those things?

Edit: One thought is to use Mono.Cecil to rewrite references to System.Console to Renraku.System.Console or somesuch, but I'd prefer to work within the framework if possible.

Comment: In your specific problem, cant to just to implement a TraceListener and to use a Trace.Write?

Comment: @Rubens Farias: That's a good idea w.r.t. output, but won't allow input hooking, console settings affecting our actual consoles, etc.

Comment: From what I understand you are trying to build a Virtual Machine Host, not an OS.

Comment: @Cody, and what about to use a `<assemblyBinding />`?

Comment: @Jader Dias: No, it's very much an OS.  It runs bare metal right now (compiles itself down to machine code), but everything outside of the memory/object/interrupt managers is able to run on top of any .NET implementation.

Comment: @Rubens Farias: As far as I'm aware, assemblyBinding will only allow wholesale replacement of libraries.  Is there a way to make assemblyBinding only load a certain class (or set of classes) from a different library?

Comment: Why do you want to rewire System.Console? Is it because you want that .NET applications that run on top of your OS to use it and write in your OS console instead of the .NET host environment one?

Comment: @Jader Dias: Applications running in Renraku (the OS) use System.Console like normal, but it gets redirected to a service that handles it properly.  The console could be a normal 'console' window, or any other target that the given console service implements.  Without being able to do this, things like consoles inside the Renraku GUI won't work.

At this point it's starting to look like using Mono.Cecil to rewrite the assembly to point to a different System.Console is the easiest way.

Comment: This sounds pretty cool. Is it a public project or something private? I'd love to take a look if it's public.

Comment: It's all public.  You can see the source at http://github.com/daeken/RenrakuOS/ and read more about the project at http://daeken.com/renraku-future-os

Comment: If all you want is to manipulate Console streams, you could use Console.SetIn, Console.SetError, Console.SetOut functions. If you want to replace selective classes in an assembly, I am afraid there is no simple way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into the free tool [PostSharp](http://www.postsharp.org/).  It allows you to change existing .Net assemblies at design time by automating the modification of the MSIL.

See [this page](http://www.postsharp.org/aop-net/compiletime-weaving) for more information on compile-time weaving in PostSharp. and [this page](http://www.postsharp.org/aop-net/runtime-weaving) for information on load-time weaving (occurs at runtime just before the assembly is loaded in memory).

For Runtime weaving (modifying existing methods at runtime), look at [LinFu](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LinFuPart6.aspx).

> [Except from page]
>
> ... you can use LinFu.AOP to dynamically intercept any method on any type, regardless of whether or not the method is declared virtual or non-virtual. You’ll also be able to dynamically intercept (and even replace) methods declared on sealed types, in addition to any static methods that are declared on that type.
>
> [/Except from page]

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Not perfect for my case, but it seems to be the best I'll do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking just to redirect standard in and standard out? If so, [Console.SetIn(TextReader in)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setin.aspx) and [Console.SetOut(TextWriter out)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout.aspx) are exactly what you're looking for.

As far as other methods go, I'm pretty sure they'll all go through mscorlib at some point. If can't afford that, you may end up writing your own Console class after all.

Comment: We need lower level access to the console, e.g. colors, buffer size, etc.  Thus we need to be able to replace the whole class.  It's looking like the only way to go about this is to use Mono.Cecil to rewrite references.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think with your restrictions to third party you can switch from system.console. why not write a new class with what you wanted or search for an open source stuff.

There is one more alternative is to use windows powershell, but i think that will also not work in your case

Answer (score 0):

how about indirecting on the console methods. Use reflection to load up function pointers to the functions you need and then you can have a config file that provides the actual names of the functions to use

Ie in your code you call DoConsoleRead

At load time DoConsoleRead is made to point to some arbitrary function

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be done using the References node in the Properties sheet.
Take a look at this example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/Wm2005Globalization2.aspx.
It "fixes" a class in the Compact Framework, I think you can make it work in the full framework, but I can test it right now. (No VS at work)

Answer (score 0):

How about running ROTOR (SSCLI) on your OS?
There you also have the full source code and an abstraction from the underlying OS
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=8C09FD61-3F26-4555-AE17-3121B4F51D4D&displaylang=en

Having spent some time in Reflector with MS .NET, we all know it is tightly bound to the WIN 32 API, which would only cause your OS to look more like Windows then be a new clean OS.

Other then that, rewriting references seems like a viable option.

Comment: ROTOR, being under a tainting license, would be a serious legal issue if Renraku developers were to touch it; it'd block us from being able to work on our own runtime, and make our OS effectively non-free.  Due to the architecture of the OS, platform-specific (hosted) features are isolated to different services, allowing us to maintain our own style.  It looks like reference rewriting is the best way to go about it.

Comment: Cody, I've been looking into more Managed OS'es. And I now totally see your point. It seems like similar minded people from COSMOS and MOSA are having the same issues.
Seems to me you should all agree to work on 1 single 'Managed OS' if you care to be successfull. There is just too much work to spread it across (at least 3 projects).

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing the System class in the GAC?
I know Java has a bootclasspath switch define the location of the Java "bootstrap" classes-java.lang.Object, java.lang.Exception, and so forth